# Group nested array objects to parent key in JQ

Tags: jq

I have JSON coming from an external application, formatted like so:

```
   {
      "ticket_fields": [
      {
        "url": "https://example.com/1122334455.json",
        "id": 1122334455,
        "type": "tagger",
        "custom_field_options": [
          {
            "id": 123456789,
            "name": "I have a problem",
            "raw_name": "I have a problem",
            "value": "help_i_have_problem",
            "default": false
          },
          {
            "id": 456789123,
            "name": "I have feedback",
            "raw_name": "I have feedback",
            "value": "help_i_have_feedback",
            "default": false
          },
        ]
      }
      {
        "url": "https://example.com/6677889900.json",
        "id": 6677889900,
        "type": "tagger",
        "custom_field_options": [
          {
            "id": 321654987,
            "name": "United States,
            "raw_name": "United States",
            "value": "location_123_united_states",
            "default": false
          },
          {
            "id": 987456321,
            "name": "Germany",
            "raw_name": "Germany",
            "value": "location_456_germany",
            "default": false
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

The end goal is to be able to get the data into a TSV in the sense that each object in the custom_field_options array is grouped by the parent ID (`ticket_fields.id`), and then transposed such that each object would be represented on a single line, like so:

| Ticket Field ID | Name | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1122334455 | I have a problem | help_i_have_problem |
| 1122334455 | I have feedback | help_i_have_feedback |
| 6677889900 | United States | location_123_united_states |
| 6677889900 | Germany | location_456_germany |

I have been able to export the data successfully to TSV already, but it reads per-line, and without preserving order, like so:

*Using `jq -r '.ticket_fields[] | select(.type=="tagger") | [.id, .custom_field_options[].name, .custom_field_options[].value] | @tsv'`*

| Ticket Field ID | Name | Name | Value | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1122334455 | I have a problem | I have feedback | help_i_have_problem | help_i_have_feedback |
| 6677889900 | United States | Germany | location_123_united_states | location_456_germany |

Each of the `custom_field_options` arrays in production may consist of any number of objects (not limited to 2 each). But I seem to be stuck on how to appropriately group or map these objects to their parent `ticket_fields.id` and to transpose the data in a clean manner. The `select(.type=="tagger")` is mentioned in the query as there are multiple values for `ticket_fields.type` which need to be filtered out.

Based on another answer on here, I did try variants of `jq -r '.ticket_fields[] | select(.type=="tagger") | map(.custom_field_options |= from_entries) | group_by(.custom_field_options.ticket_fields) | map(map( .custom_field_options |= to_entries))'`  without success. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two nested iterations, one in each array. Save the value of `.id` in a variable to access it later.

```sh
jq -r '
  .ticket_fields[] | select(.type=="tagger") | .id as $id
  | .custom_field_options[] | [$id, .name, .value]
  | @tsv
'
```

Comment: This worked beautifully. Thank you - learning more about jQ daily :)